# Hide block html

Tags: attributes

i have text attribute: gesamtpreis, now i need check if attribute empty - hide block html with attribute, if value have in attribute gesamtpreis - then display block

for my attribute display i use code:

```
<?php $attribute = $simpleProduct->getResource()->getAttribute('gesamtpreis');
    if ($simpleProduct)
        {
        echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($simpleProduct);
        }
    ?>
```

let me know how i can do better hide or show block via attribute value, Thanks

Comment: Probably the `if` statement should check the attribute, not the product.

Comment: Possible example how can do better?